# Trouble writing cube root function

Tags: c++, root, cube

I'm trying to write a cube root function named `double my_cbrt_1(double n)` using the following pseudocode:

```
x = 1
repeat 10 times:  x = (2x + n / x2) / 3
return x
```

and then write a main which prints n, cbrt(n), and my_cbrt_1(n) for n = 3.14159 times 10 to the kth power for k = -100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, and 100.  Use this C++11 code (which only works on linux2):

```
for(auto k : {-100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100}){
    n = 3.14159 * pow(10.0, k);
    //cout goes here
}
```

I'm having trouble getting started on this. If anyone could help me that would be great!

Comment: and how far did you come? where did you get stuck?

Comment: SO is not the right place for explaining how code/pseudocode works or learn algorithms or languages. Is it a homework question?

Comment: I haven't gotten anywhere actually lol, need helping getting started. Im a noob at c++

Comment: If you're entirely new to c++, start with a "hello world" tutorial and work your way up.

Comment: I think you mean `x = (2x + n / x^2) / 3`

Comment: Why you don't do your Cube root formula like this x^(1/3)

Comment: @jordsti - The OP is supposed to be using the Newton-Raphson method to find the cube root. That x=(2x+n/x^2)/3 is the Newton-Raphson update.

Answer (score 2):

To get started, you should probably calculate the cubed root of a single number once, and then you can use that same function for new numbers

To simply implement the function that you were given

```
double my_cbrt_1(double n)
{
    double x = 1.0;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        x = (2.0*x + n / (x*x)) / 3.0;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: you should replace `x2` by `x*x` ! The formula of the OP is wrong !

Comment: @hivert  might have been a typo by the OP trying to copy superscripts

Comment: You'll have order of operations issues in your formula.  It should be:   `x = ((2.0 * x) + (n / (x * x))) / 3.0;`

Comment: it would be better to set up a convergence criteria.

Comment: thats what I actually got! i'm somewhat confused of what they are asking for the main

Comment: It may be easier to write it as `double x2 = x * x; double x3 = x * x * x; x = (n + (2 * x3)) / ( 3 * x2);`